# SQL Is it possible to return multiple values and display them in a single column?

Tags: sql

I am having an issue formatting the output to a query as we need to update it, we calculate price quantity breaks for our products but I now need them in a single field so when we export them the formatting is correct, the current script I use

```
SELECT 'Manufacturer', 'ManufacturerPartNumber', 'Price1Quantity','Price1', 'Price2Quantity', 'Price2','Price3Quantity', 'Price3', 'Price4Quantity', 'Price4','Price5Quantity', 'Price5'
union all
SELECT
  manufact.name AS 'Manufacturer',
  item.item_no AS 'ManufacturerPartNumber',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_1 IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price1Quantity',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_1 IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN price.prc_1 = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE price.prc_1
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price1',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.qty_1 IS NULL THEN price.qty_1
    WHEN price.qty_1 = 9999999 AND
      price.prc_2 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_1 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_1 = 9999999 THEN price.qty_1
    ELSE price.qty_1 + 1
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price2Quantity',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_2 IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN price.prc_2 = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE price.prc_2
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price2',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.qty_2 IS NULL THEN price.qty_2
    WHEN price.qty_2 = 9999999 AND
      price.prc_3 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_2 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_2 = 9999999 THEN price.qty_2
    ELSE price.qty_2 + 1
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price3Quantity',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_3 IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN price.prc_3 = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE price.prc_3
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price3',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.qty_3 IS NULL THEN price.qty_3
    WHEN price.qty_3 = 9999999 AND
      price.prc_4 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_3 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_3 = 9999999 THEN price.qty_3
    ELSE price.qty_3 + 1
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price4Quantity',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_4 IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN price.prc_4 = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE price.prc_4
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price4',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.qty_4 IS NULL THEN price.qty_4
    WHEN price.qty_4 = 9999999 AND
      price.prc_5 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_4 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_4 = 9999999 THEN price.qty_4
    ELSE price.qty_4 + 1
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price5Quantity',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_5 IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN price.prc_5 = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE price.prc_5
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price5'

From item
```

Which currently outputs the price and quantity breaks in there own field, but what I need is it in a list seperated by '|'.
The current output is similar to this

```
Manufacturer |  ManufacturerPartNumber  | Price1Quantity    |   Price1   |  Price2Quantity      | Price2    |   Price3Quantity      |  Price3       |  Price4Quantity       |  Price4    |  Price5Quantity   |  Price5
comp1        |      02-84744213         |   1               |    0.8     |      7               |  0.4      |       26              |  0.24         |   209                 |   0.16     |      NULL         |  NULL
comp2        |      02-84744214         |   1               |   0.274    |      25              |  0.249    |       100             |  0.228        |   250                 |   0.211    |      NULL         |  NULL
comp3        |      02-84744215         |   1               |   0.306    |      25              |  0.284    |       100             |  0.265        |   NULL                |   NULL     |      NULL         |  NULL
comp4        |      02-84744216         |   1               |   0.049    |      25              |  0.045    |       100             |  0.042        |   NULL                |   NULL     |      NULL         |  NULL
```

But what I need is something like this

```
Manufacturer |  ManufacturerPartNumber  | PriceQuantity              |           Price1             | 
comp1        |      02-84744213         |   1 | 7 | 26 | 209         |    0.8|0.4|0.24|0.16         |
comp2        |      02-84744214         |   1 | 25 | 100 | 250       |   0.274|0.249|0.228|0.211    |
comp3        |      02-84744215         |   1 | 25 | 100             |      0.306|0.284|0.265       |
comp4        |      02-84744216         |   1 | 25 | 100             |      0.049|0.045|0.042       |
```

So each pull for quantity and price are put in the same field separated by a '|'
Is this possible ? does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your DB engine? While there's overlap and similarities, Oracle handles things differently from MS SQL, which is different from MySQL, etc.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: its MS SQL that i am using as my database engine

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Depending your DB engine you probably have `concat` or similar function.

https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/3605/concatenate

So in your case example:

(You usually don't select titles for columns, so I dropped it from here)

```sql
SELECT
  manufact.name AS 'Manufacturer',
  item.item_no AS 'ManufacturerPartNumber',
  CONCAT(
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_1 IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
  END) AS varchar),'|',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.qty_1 IS NULL THEN price.qty_1
    WHEN price.qty_1 = 9999999 AND
      price.prc_2 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_1 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_1 = 9999999 THEN price.qty_1
    ELSE price.qty_1 + 1
  END) AS varchar),'|',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.prc_2 IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN price.prc_2 = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE price.prc_2
  END) AS varchar) AS 'Price2',
  CAST((CASE
    WHEN price.qty_2 IS NULL THEN price.qty_2
    WHEN price.qty_2 = 9999999 AND
      price.prc_3 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_2 = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN price.qty_2 = 9999999 THEN price.qty_2
    ELSE price.qty_2 + 1
  END) AS varchar),'|') as PriceQty

From item
```

I shortened it a but, but you probably got idea.

Is this wise to do in SQL query is another question. I'd fetch numeric data from SQL and modify presentation in app.

Comment: Thank you for the help I will give that a shot,  yea we named the columns as this gets exported into a txt doc and then ftp'd  out to our hosting site so its automated hence why doing it in SQL is the way we are doing it.